# SQL Getting data by the hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a weather database in SQL Server 2008 that is filled with weather observations that are taken every 20 minutes. I want to get the weather records for each hour not every 20 minutes how can I filter out some the results so only the first observation for each hour is in the results.

Example:

```
7:00:00
7:20:00
7:40:00
8:00:00
```

Desired Output

```
7:00:00 
8:00:00
```

Comment: Does every hour have rows for each 20min increment, or are there any gaps?

Comment: Apply a WHERE condition like that: `WHERE datepart(minute, hour_column) = <here_desired_minutes>`. In your case that would be 00 for each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get exactly (less the fact that it's an `INT` instead of a `TIME`; nothing hard to fix) what you listed as your desired result,

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp)
FROM Observations
```

You could also add in `CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE)` if you wanted that as well.

---

Assuming you want the data as well, however, it depends a little, but from exactly what you've described, the simple solution is just to say:

```
SELECT *
FROM Observations
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, TimeStamp) = 0
```

That fails if you have missing data, though, which is pretty common.

---

If you do have some hours where you want data but don't have a row at :00, you could do something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE), DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp) ORDER BY TimeStamp)
    FROM Observations
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE n = 1
```

That'll take the first one for any date/hour combination.

Of course, you're still leaving out anything where you had no data for an entire hour. That would require a numbers table, if you even want to return those instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like the following one to get the nearest hour of a time point (in this case it's `GETUTCDATE()`).

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, GETUTCDATE()) / 60 * 60, 0)
```

Then you can use this formula in the `WHERE` clause of your SQL query to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to `GROUP BY` your desired time frame, like the date and the hours. Then, you get the `MIN` value of the timeframe. Since you didn't specify which columns you are using, this is the most generic thing i can give.

Answer (score 0):

Use as filter :

```
... where DATEPART(MINUTE, DateColumn) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter the result for every whole hour, you can set your where clause to check for 00 minute since every whole hour is HH:00:00.

To get the minute part from a time-stamp, you can use DATEPART function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLENAME
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, YOURDATEFIELDNAME) = 0
```

More information on datepart function can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp